# Best way to transport JavaScript data between tabs/windows

Tags: javascript, signalr

I have a server that pushes a notification using SignalR to a user. The current setup on JS is the tab with current focus will get the notification (all other tabs are on pause since they’re not on focus).  Once the user switches tabs, they won’t see any notification since the first tab already received it.

Question: What’s the best practice for other tabs to see the notification (if it hasn’t been processed yet by the first tab)? Is it to create a session on the user end and track it between browsers? Or possibly keep it on the server and it’ll keep pushing it to every tab until it’s processed by one of the tabs?

Comment: You might consider to broadcast notifications to other tabs via something like local storage events... here is a pen: https://codepen.io/eisneim/pen/wBeqpN, also see https://www.npmjs.com/package/crosstab

Answer (score 0):

You can use **window.onfocus** and **window.onblur** to detect when a user visits tab.:

http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/detect-browser-window-focus

Comment: I’m currently doing that, my question is how to transfer the data/ keep the data consistent when they switch tabs

Comment: Stored your data to client local, when client visit, load stored data like client have new event emited.